# Как красить пиксели в python?

Tags: python, изображения

Хочу сделать нейросеть на python которая будет генерировать картинки, можете подсказать какую - нибудь библиотеку в которой можно красить пиксели по цветовой модели RGB?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу посоветовать, например, библиотеку [Pillow (форк PIL)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). На всякий случай вот пример вопроса касательно прорисовки пикселей: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346063/how-to-draw-square-pixel-by-pixel-python-pil)

Comment: Лучше в ответе помимо ссылки-источника приводить код :)

Comment: @gil9red Тем более, что код там совсем коротенький, да )